# Properly sizing ParaView plots for LaTeX

Tags: visualization, paraview

I would like to make a visualization with ParaView for a paper. In order to have a high quality look, I would like the image to be, say, 300 dpi (or vector graphics). Moreover, since I know the column width of the paper, I'd like to somehow specify that width in ParaView so I can adjust the size of the visualization, colorbars, etc., to make it fit within the column. I'd also like to specify the text size and font to be the same as in LaTeX. In other words, I do not want to rescale the image afterwards, because that makes the text too small or too large. In other programs I usually figure out how to do this, but so far no luck in ParaView. Even if I set the font to, say, 10 pt, it turns out way too small when I include the figure in LaTeX with `scale=1`. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. This question is probably off-topic in this site. Nevertheless, you could do the math to estimate the size that you need for your figure. Let's say that you need a single column figure ([90 mm](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/artwork-and-media-instructions/artwork-sizing)) then you want it to be 1063 pixels wide. If you select a text size of 8 pt it is OK. Now, if you need to double the resolution of your image you would need to scale the text size proportionally.

Comment: @nicoguaro: Thank you. I'll try to follow your approach and see what comes out of it. I'll happily have the question moved to another, more suitable SE site if any moderators wish to do that for me.

Comment: @nicoguaro: I tried what you said, choosing the number of pixels to be appropriate for 300 dpi at one column width. However, the text size I choose in ParaView still do not correspond at all to what I get on the picture when scaled to one column width.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the scaling depends on the size of your scene in your screen. Regarding the migration, I don't know which site is more appropriate because it does not seem to be for SE either?